# Remove duplicate combination of elements from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-7

I have an array with fields:

```
$products = array(
    [0] => array('name' => 'product_one', 'category' => 'category_one', employee => '3234'),
    [1] => array('name' => 'product_two', 'category' => 'category_two', employee => '5421'),
    [2] => array('name' => 'product_three', 'category' => 'category_one', employee => '3234'),
    [3] => array('name' => 'product_one', 'category' => 'category_one', employee => '2153'),
    [4] => array('name' => 'product_one', 'category' => 'category_two', employee => '6312')        
)
```

Now, in this case, `employee` field is not important, but the combination of `product`/`category` is unique.

Wanted result:

```
$products = array(
    [0] => array('name' => 'product_one', 'category' => 'category_one', employee => '3234'),
    [1] => array('name' => 'product_two', 'category' => 'category_two', employee => '5421'),
    [2] => array('name' => 'product_three', 'category' => 'category_one', employee => '3234'),
    [4] => array('name' => 'product_one', 'category' => 'category_two', employee => '6312')        
)
```

Any idea what is the best way to do this? On production, I have more than 30.000 elements and usually around 10 duplicates. Also in real database, I have 12 fields and a combination of 4 of them needs to be unique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind which of the duplicates you keep, it's probably simplest to iterate over the loop, making a new array with keys which are a combination of the required unique values (I've used a separator of `##` in this code, you can use anything that *cannot* occur in the values). This way duplicates will be automatically removed as an array cannot have identical keys. Once the loop is done the output array can be re-indexed numerically using `array_values`:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($products as $p) {
    $output["{$p['name']}##{$p['category']}"] = $p;
}

$output = array_values($output);
print_r($output);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => product_one
            [category] => category_one
            [employee] => 2153
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => product_two
            [category] => category_two
            [employee] => 5421
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => product_three
            [category] => category_one
            [employee] => 3234
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => product_one
            [category] => category_two
            [employee] => 6312
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jQDb0)

Comment: Work like a charm!